# Should AVL tree for a set of data always have the same answer?

Tags: algorithm, search, avl-tree

If I have the following set of data, are there multiple answers to it?

```
3,5,11,8,4,1,12,7,2,6,10,9
```

Can there be multiple answers? Or only condition is the balancing factor be -1, 0, 1? And hence any number of answer is possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "answer"?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 I mean, can there be multiple tree implementation? Thank you for response

Comment: implementation? Like representation?

Comment: I mean, the tree. Can there be multiple trees representation for the same data set?

Comment: The structure of the avl tree for a sorted set depends on the sequence of insertions.

Comment: So the representation can be different but should be same if insertion sequence is same? @CoronA Thank you